# Giving the date column "today's" date if less than today

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I currently have a query in my access database which returns the following values.

```
ItemCode    ComponentReadyDate
5109123 
5113014 
5113035      23/09/2013 
5109121      13/09/2013 
5109122      13/09/2013 
5107000      09/09/2013 
5107000      30/09/2013 
5109088      18/09/2013 
5109092      24/09/2013 
5109092      28/10/2013 
5109110 
5109110      31/07/2013 
5101002A    
5102412      02/10/2013 
5102412      03/09/2013
```

Is there a way that I can modify this query so that if the ComponentReadyDate is before today's date, it's changed to todays day for example;

```
ItemCode    ComponentReadyDate
    5109123      30/09/2013
    5113014      30/09/2013
    5113035      30/09/2013
    5109121      30/09/2013 
    5109122      30/09/2013 
    5107000      30/09/2013
    5107000      30/09/2013
    5109088      30/09/2013 
    5109092      30/09/2013 
    5109092      28/10/2013 
    5109110      30/09/2013
    5109110      30/09/2013
    5101002A     30/09/2013
    5102412      02/10/2013 
    5102412      30/09/2013
```

Answer (score 2):

This query seems to do the trick:

```
SELECT
    ItemCode,
    Switch(IsNull(oldReadyDate),Date(),oldReadyDate<Date(),Date(),True,oldReadyDate) AS ComponentReadyDate
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            ItemCode,
            ComponentReadyDate AS oldReadyDate
        FROM
            Components
    )
```